# What is the meaning of 実質負担金額?

Tags: words, meaning, kanji

I want to buy new phone but I am unable to understand the meaning of 実質負担金額.

[image]

Please help me to understand this.

Comment: Did you look up any part of this in a dictionary?

Comment: yes.... But I didn't get any intuitive meaning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you break it down into 実質、負担、金額...

実質 is 'real', 'actual', etc.
負担 is your burden, as in to bear a cost.
金額 is an amount of money.

So, the actual cost you will bear, the amount you're actually going to have to pay.

If you have a look, it looks like there's a set cost for the phone, but if you take away the monthly discount (24 months worth), this is the amount you will "actually" end up paying.